# Problem with HibernateTemplate

Tags: hibernate

I am integrating Spring and Hibernate. My spring.xml is:

```
<bean id="sessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="myDataSource" />
    <property name="mappingResources">
        <list>
            <value>
                resources/User.hbm.xml
                <!-- Project.hbm.xml ProjCF.hbm.xml Task.hbm.xml TaskCF.hbm.xml Category.hbm.xml 
                    TaskEstimation.hbm.xml ProjectEstimation.hbm.xml Parameter.hbm.xml StatisticTool.hbm.xml 
                    Report.hbm.xml -->
            </value>
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect"> org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="myUserDAO" class="main.java.com.gwt.app.server.User">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
</bean>
```

And on my User class:

```
public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sessionFactory){
    this.hibernateTemplate = new HibernateTemplate(sessionFactory);
}

public User loadUser(String log){
    return (User)hibernateTemplate.load("User", log);
}
```

The problem is that hibernateTemplate is null, could anyone help me????
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must not call `new User()` but you have to ask Spring for the bean (`appContext.getBean("myUserDAO", User.class)`)

Answer (score 0):

Define the hibernate template in the spring xml as well don't use the new keyword. Below is sample config and classes.

```
<bean id="yourHibernateTemplate" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate">
    <property name="sessionFactory">
        <ref bean="yourSessionFactory"/>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="yourRootDAO" class="woc.dao.base.RootDAOImpl" abstract="true">
    <property name="hibernateTemplate" ref="yourHibernateTemplate"/>
</bean>

<bean id="comboValueDAO" parent="yourRootDAO" class="woc.dao.impl.ComboValueDAOImpl" />



import java.io.Serializable;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateCallback;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.HibernateDaoSupport;


public abstract class RootDAOImpl<T> extends HibernateDaoSupport implements RootDAO<T> {

    protected Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(getClass());
    private Class<T> clazz;

    public RootDAOImpl(Class<T> clazz) {
        this.clazz = clazz;
    }

    public void delete(T entity) {
        //Mark entity as deleted
        try{
            Method setDeletedMethod = clazz.getDeclaredMethod("setDeleted", Boolean.class);
            setDeletedMethod.invoke(entity, true);
            getHibernateTemplate().saveOrUpdate(entity);        
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        //actually delete
//      getHibernateTemplate().delete(entity);
    }
    @Override
    public void deleteAll(Collection<T> entities) {
        getHibernateTemplate().deleteAll(entities);
    }
    @Override
    public void saveOrUpdateAll(Collection<T> entities) {
        getHibernateTemplate().saveOrUpdateAll(entities);
    }
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    public T get(Serializable id) {
        return (T)getHibernateTemplate().get(clazz, id);
    }
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    public T load(Serializable id) {
        return (T)getHibernateTemplate().load(clazz, id);
    }
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    public List<T> find(String hql){
        return (List<T>)getHibernateTemplate().find(hql);
    }       
    @Override
    public Object execute(HibernateCallback action) {
        return getHibernateTemplate().execute(action);
    }
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    public List<T> findByNamedParam(String queryString, String paramName,Object value) {
        return getHibernateTemplate().findByNamedParam(queryString, paramName, value);
    }
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    public List<T> findByNamedParam(String queryString, String[] paramNames,Object[] values) {
        return getHibernateTemplate().findByNamedParam(queryString, paramNames, values);
    }       
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    public List<T> getByExampleList(T entity) {
        return getHibernateTemplate().findByExample(entity);
    }
    @Override
    public T getByExampleUnique(T entity) {
        return null;
    }
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    public List<T> listAll() {
        return getHibernateTemplate().loadAll(clazz);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    public List<T> loadAll() {
        return getHibernateTemplate().loadAll(clazz);
    }
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    public T save(T entity) {
        return (T)getHibernateTemplate().save(entity);      
    }
    @Override
    public void saveOrUpdate(T entity) {
        getHibernateTemplate().saveOrUpdate(entity);
    }
    @Override
    public void update(T entity) {
        getHibernateTemplate().update(entity);
    }
}



import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateCallback;

public interface RootDAO<T> {

    public List<T> loadAll();

    public T save(T entity);

    public void delete(T entity);

    public T get(Serializable id);

    public T load(Serializable id);

    public void saveOrUpdate(T entity);

    public void deleteAll(Collection<T> entities);

    public void saveOrUpdateAll(Collection<T> entities);

    public List<T> find(String hql);

    public void update(T entity);

    public T getByExampleUnique(T entity);

    public List<T> getByExampleList(T entity);

    public List<T> listAll();

    public Object execute(HibernateCallback action);

    public List<T> findByNamedParam(String queryString, String paramName,Object value);

    public List<T> findByNamedParam(String queryString, String[] paramNames,Object[] values);
}



public interface ComboValueDAO extends RootDAO<ComboValue>{

}


public class ComboValueDAOImpl extends RootDAOImpl<ComboValue> implements ComboValueDAO {

    public ComboValueDAOImpl() {
        super(ComboValue.class);
    }

}
```

In your code, getHibernateTemplate() and do whatever you require.